# Is HDFS implemented on top of Hadoop's key value store? How?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I had always assumed the answer was yes, HDFS is implemented on top of Hadoop Key-Value store but I don't see any evidence (no I'm not going to read the source code!). I was hoping an article, document or paper would explain how HDFS manipulates the key-value NoSQL storage metamodel to implement the basic file operations like read, append, list directory, get metadata etc. Come to think of it, I wonder if AWS's S3 is also built on a NoSQL database.

Logically, I think you can model a file system using a key-value store where each pair represents a line in a file, which makes appending new data to large files a lot faster than a conventional file. But I would like to see if there are other practical considerations.

#### Why I'm asking

AWS S3 doesn't support appending to files and I really really want a persistent cloud storage that does AND I want the persistent storage to be accessible as a file system (so no RDBMS, KV, Columnar, Document DBs etc). I am wondering if HDFS is the answer to my application's needs.

Comment: Actually after continuing to search the web, I'm beginning to think Hadoop KV store is implemented on top of HDFS, which would be embarassing.

Comment: Hadoop is not a KV store... Not sure what you mean. It's also not a NoSQL database. HDFS is a FileSystem (like any other DFS, not really a kv-store) and YARN is a framework for abstracting memory and cpu resources (not a database).

Comment: Oh, that’s even more embarrassing. So what is the key value store that hbase is built on?

Comment: HBase is a key value store built on top of HDFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Hadoop is not a Key-Value store like Riak. HBase is the NoSQL database that I'm thinking of, but that's not a simple key-value store, it's a columnar store.

Moreover, I think the opposite of what I thought is true: HBase is built on top of HDFS, not vice versa.

Comment: Rather than Hbase, you might want to look at Accumulo